# Compare subfolders name

Tags: c#, directory, subdirectory

I'm not sure what the correct question for my case would be but I'll try to describe as good as I can. I have to mention that I don't have much knowledge of this language, I'm using it strictly for the executable of my appplication, mainly I mess around with Java. So I have an app that only starts up if it finds java in my PC. I'm using something like this:

```
ProcessStartInfo startJava = new ProcessStartInfo("java", JavaProcessArguments());
startJava.CreateNoWindow = !client.ShowConsole;
startJava.UseShellExecute = false;
```

But, let's say I want to use openJDK, then I would have to change "java" to something like this:

```
ProcessStartInfo startJava = new ProcessStartInfo
(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\openJDK_1.7\bin\java.exe", JavaProcessArguments());
```

Moving on, I wanted to start openJDK FIRST, even if java is present, so I wrote a condition that does that:

```
    private void StartTheProcess()
    {   
        string pathJDK = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\openJDK_1.7\bin\";
        bool isDirJDK7 = Directory.Exists(pathJDK);
        if (isDirJDK7)
        {   
            ProcessStartInfo startJava = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\openJDK_1.7\bin\java.exe", JavaProcessArguments());
            startJava.CreateNoWindow = !client.ShowConsole;
            startJava.UseShellExecute = false;
            try
            {
                using (Process p = Process.Start(startJava))
                {
                    p.WaitForExit();
                }
            }
            catch (Win32Exception ex)
            {
                some error...
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                some error...
            }
        }
        else
        {
                ProcessStartInfo startJava = new ProcessStartInfo("java", JavaProcessArguments());
                startJava.CreateNoWindow = !client.ShowConsole;
                startJava.UseShellExecute = false;
                try
                {
                    using (Process p = Process.Start(startJava))
                    {
                        p.WaitForExit();
                    }
                }
                catch (Win32Exception ex)
                {
                    some error...
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    some error...
                }
        }
     }
```

Now let's suppose I have more openJDK versions in the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\"   folder: openJDK_1.7, openJDK_1.7_u1, openJDK_1.8, so on, and I want to start the latest one. How should I accomplish this? I think one method would be to compare the subfolders names found there but I don't really know how to. The content of all the subfolders is identical and the names of the subfolders have the same construction (openJDK_1.X / openJDK_1.X_uYZ). Could you help me, based on this poorly (most likely) code? :D

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you could try,

Split the directory name string by 
`var version = string.split('_')`, and then the version would be `version[1] = "1.7"`, you can convert all of these into doubles/decimals/floats,etc and just sort the data out, get the latest version (the one with the highest number and get its directory back

The second thing you can try is checking the `Directory.GetLastWriteTime(String)`, which you can compare, and find the last one, please not that this is not reliable at all since the folder can be changed by anything.

Comment: Is it necessary to split and turn to number? Are the foldernames such that they are alphabetically sorted into the correct sequence? List of folder names that start with `"openJDK"`, ordered by name, take the last?

Comment: Thank you, will try it!

Comment: @SazooCat, that is what I am thinking from the question wording

Comment: @SazooCat Yes, they are sorted so I need to check the numbers, whichever has the highest number is the one I am looking for. Pattern is openJDK_1.7 or 1.8, followed or not by _u and then another number

Comment: Maybe it would be more robust if you check the assemblyversion information of the java.exe file? Just as a different idea of approach...

Comment: A very relevant example code snippet in the microsoft reference page...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getdirectories?view=netframework-4.7.2

You'd probably want to engage some .OrderBy() and .Last() calls onto the resulting list?